# parsing html using beautifulsoup and storing in pandas

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to parse the following website using BeautifulSoup: https://www.treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/press/press_secannpr.htm

Expanding the Bills -> Term:52- Week will show 1 row of a multi-index Pandas dataframe I am building, where the first index will be the Term:Horizon and the second will be Announcement Dates.

My issue lies in using BeautifulSoup to find these values because I can't seem to find any unique identifiers by reading the HTML. I assume I would iterate over Bills, then over Term-52Week and build a dictionary, but I'm not sure how to begin the process.

Where should I begin? (Is there perhaps a better library?)

Comment: There is an json endpoint  for the same . can you try that please ?
URL :  https://www.treasurydirect.gov/TA_WS/securities/search?startDate=2018-01-01&endDate=2018-12-31&compact=false&dateFieldName=auctionDate&format=json&filterscount=0&groupscount=2&group0=z3a&group1=t3a&pagenum=0&pagesize=500&recordstartindex=0&recordendindex=18&_=1533847141834

Comment: Wow, I had no idea this was available. I assume this is more efficient and removes the parsing necessity. Do you know if it is possible to dynamically build out a multi-indexed pandas dataframe as I encounter new items, or should it all be hardcoded?

Comment: If you're talking about [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html) then yeah, you can append new items .

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you reach the json endpoint manually as opposed to simply visiting that URL?

Comment: Sure . I was looking for `xhr` in my network console requests to see if the app had any `ajax` requests sent. Luckily there were 4 such requests one of which had the data that you needed.

Comment: @MadhanVaradhodiyil thanks for the insight, I'm assuming that this json is a live endpoint of the data on that site and not one that you need to create manually every time , thanks again!

Comment: @Evarsite Galios . I guess it's a live end point , the data changes if we change the query parameters. No problem :)

Comment: Yep . https://www.treasurydirect.gov/TA_WS/securities/search?startDate=1997-01-01&endDate=1997-12-31&compact=false&dateFieldName=auctionDate&format=json&tips=Yes . Was this the one you were looking for?

Comment: It seems like there was a flag in the original query that was somehow altering the output and preventing the earlier data from being fetched, however I built it from scratch and it's all working now. Thanks.

Comment: Ah Cool. :) No problem